# How to validate JSON schema in java?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I try to check user detail object with use JSON schema. But I don't know how to check JSON object in Java.

My Schema:

```
{
     "type" : "object",
     "properties" : {
     "first_name" : {
                     "type" : "string" , 
                     "minLength"  : 3 , 
                     "maxLength" : 255 
                  }, 
   "last_name" : {
                     "type" : "string" , 
                     "minLength"  : 3 , 
                     "maxLength" : 255 
                  },
    "age"       : { 
                     "type" : "integer" , 
                     "minimum" : 16 ,
                      "maximum" : 40
                  },
    "phone_number" : {
                        "type" : "integer",
                        "pattern" : "[6-9][0-9]{9}"
                     } ,
     "email"     : { 
                       "type" : "string",
                       "pattern" : "[a-z0-9]+"
                   } , 
     "password" : { 
                       "type" : "string" ,
                       "minLength" : 7 ,
                       "maxLength" : 255 ,
                       "pattern" : "^.{7, 255}$"
                  } , 
      "gender" : { "enum" : ["Male" , "Female"] }   
},

"required" : ["first_name","last_name" , "age"  ,"email" , "password" 
, "gender" ]
}
```

My Sample Input:

```
{
"first_name" : "Sample" ,
"last_name" : "Name" ,
"age"  : 19,
"gender" : "Male",
"phone_number"  :  9080245591,
"email" : "samplle@gmail.com",
"password" : "uni=versity"
}
```

Any one can say how to check this input with use JSON schema in Java.

Comment: Java doesn't have native JSON support, so you need JSON library for processing JSON. Your question is basically "What JSON library can check JSON file using JSON schema?", and that is off-topic for StackOverflow: ***Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow***. Do you even have a JSON Schema?

Comment: @Andreas his example gives a JSON Schema, He didn't really ask for a Library.

Comment: @pdem Guess I shouldn't comment at 3 AM, when I can't even see the JSON schema right in front of me. DOH! But the question really is a request to find a library, otherwise why would both answers (incl. yours) be doing just that?

Comment: @Andreas Well, ok :). I just didn't find a minimal working example of this on stackoverflow,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use FasterXML jackson with the module:json-schema-validator  as holten proposed.

Include it in maven:

    com.github.java-json-tools
    json-schema-validator
    2.2.8

Complementary to this, to generate schema from object instead of writing it manually you can also use another module:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema

I may add a functional example if needed

Answer (score 12):

The [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) in GitHub, Perhaps It will help you to check the json object in java.